# the qt app shows Chinese in messy code on windows when using UTF-8 encoding-format

Tags: windows, qt, cmd, utf-8, chinese-locale

I developed a simple qt app on windows to test the qt Chinese UTF-8 encoding-format:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString strMessage = QString::fromLocal8Bit("我是UTF8编码的文件：");
    qDebug() << strMessage;
    return a.exec();
}
```

and my main.cpp file encoding format is UTF-8 without BOM, but when I run the app on windows, the app print string is "鎴戞槸UTF8缂栫爜鐨勬枃浠讹細" which I expect is "我是UTF8编码的文件：",it seems the string "我是UTF8编码的文件：" is converted to GB2312 encoding-format so shows the wrong string "鎴戞槸UTF8缂栫爜鐨勬枃浠讹細" in runtime,and the string "我是UTF8编码的文件：" shows right string "我是UTF8编码的文件：'' when the app runs on macos, I don't know why?
how to let the string "我是UTF8编码的文件：" show right on windows platform, thanks a lot!

Comment: The Problem is: Linux(and other UNIX derevates like macOS, BSD, etc) uses Unicode for it's terminal, Windows - does not. Windows' console cannot print Unicode. You can try to set codepage of windows console to codepage 65001 and use Lucida Console font for console terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, printing UTF-8 to the console is not automatic. You need to execute this command first in the console to change to codepage 65001 (which is the UTF-8 Windows codepage):

```
chcp 65001
```

You also need to set a font that offers Chinese characters. On Windows 10, that's the "NSimSun" font. However, the Windows console has a neat function where it automatically switches the font if you set a Chinese codepage (like 936). So you can actually programmatically run these commands using the standard library `system()` function. The `chcp` command produces output though. To hide it, redirect the output to `nul`.

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    // Temporary codepage change so we get an automatic font change.
    system("chcp 936 > nul");
    // Change to UTF-8.
    system("chcp 65001 > nul");
#endif

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString strMessage = QString::fromUtf8("我是UTF8编码的文件：");
    qDebug() << strMessage;
    return a.exec();
}
```

(As a side note, you should use `QString::fromUtf8()` since you know the text is in UTF-8.)

Comment: `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("GB18030"));` is good for me.